# "constructor PrisPlayer1 in class PrisPlayer1 cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a new instance of an abstract class called prisoner and make it equal to an instance of a class "PrisPlayer1" using

```
Prisoner p1 = new PrisPlayer1(rounds);
```

This returns this error:

constructor PrisPlayer1 in class PrisPlayer1 cannot be applied to given types;

required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

For the PrisPlayer1 class I have two constructors:

```
public PrisPlayer1(){
    tue = 0;
    fase = 0;
    }
```

and

```
public PrisPlayer1(int rounds){
    tue = 0;
    fase = 0;
    }
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is type of `rounds`? Why are you casting it as a `Prisoner` Kindly give more detial if you want help

Comment: You are creating an instance of Prison or PrisPlayer1, can you add more information so it becomes clear

Answer (score -1):

I don;t see any issue with the code. However do compare yours with this example ::

```
public class DummyJava {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal animal = new Dog(10);



    }
}

abstract class Animal {


}

class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog (){

    }
    public Dog (int age){

      System.out.println(" AGE ::"+age);
    }

    
}
```